# filter none on django field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model Person which sometimes has nothing in the `birth_date` field. Here is an example:

```
(Pdb) dude = Person.objects.get(pk=20)
(Pdb) dude
<Person: Bob Mandene>
(Pdb) dude.birth_date
(Pdb) dude.birth_date == None
True
```

How do I filter these records that have `birth_date == None`?

I have already tried the following with no success:

1: "birth_date__isnull" does not work.

```
 Person.objects.filter(birth_date__isnull = True) 
 # does not return the required 
 # object.    Returns a record that have birth_date set to 
 # NULL when the table was observed in MySQL.
```

The following does not return the the record with id 20.

```
Person.objects.filter(birth_date = "")
```

How do I filter on a field being None? It seems NULL and None are different. When I see the data using sequel pro (mysql graphical client) I see "0000-00-00 00:00:00", and the following did not work either

```
(Pdb) ab=Patient.objects.filter(birth_date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
 ValidationError: [u"'0000-00-00 00:00:00' value has the correct format 
 (YYYY-MM-DD     HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]) but it is an invalid date/time."]
```

**model**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    locationid = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='LocationID', blank=True) 
    address =  models.ForeignKey('Address', db_column = 'address_no')
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'person'
```

Comment: `is_null` will only work if you set `null=True` in your model; so what does the model look like?

Comment: updated the question with the model. It is a legacy table moved over from MsSQL over to MySQL.

Comment: supposedly `is_null` must work`. You must check the database if the value of the birth date is null.

Answer (score 0):

NULL in mysql turns into None in python, so what you had with birth_date__isnull=True should be returning those that  have birth_date as None.

Comment: That is what I thought too. This pic http://i.imgur.com/vYM5Qyg.png is a screenshot from sequel pro. The first line/record gets returned when I do birth_date__isnull=True. The record with id=20 is in the last line of the pic which returned True for dude.birth_date == None, and has `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the pic. I need to filter out lines that have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in them (but they are None as shown above)

Comment: What about using filter(birth_date__isnull=False) or all().exclude(birth_date__isnull=True)

Comment: filter(birth_date__isnull=False) will give me everything which is not what I want.

Comment: Try the Person.objects.all().exclude(birth_date__isnull=True) call.

Comment: Person.objects.all().exclude(birth_date__isnull=True)  returns everything.

Comment: Can you add your model definition to the original post? If I can't answer,  that might help someone else answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure why `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is casted into `None` in this case but you can try to use [`exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exact):

```
Person.objects.filter(birth_date__exact=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of list comprehension could come in handy here:

```
persons = [person for person in Person.objects.all() if not person.birth_date]
```